# Image not moving when screen changes

Tags: android, screen, screen-resolution

How can I put an image on the screen in Android so that its location doesn't change, even when I change the resolution?

this is first_frag.xml file thanks in advance..
this is the one out of three fragments that i used in my program.
hope you can help me, thank you in advance.

first_frag.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/gray" >

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/philippines_map"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:src="@drawable/title"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <DigitalClock
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/digitalClock"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Actual Time:"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/digitalClock"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:src="@drawable/bag_red"
                android:layout_above="@+id/imageView4" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:src="@drawable/bal_red"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:src="@drawable/tag_red"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView9" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:src="@drawable/mac_red"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:src="@drawable/hin_red"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView6" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:src="@drawable/tam_red"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView7" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:src="@drawable/sub_red"
                android:layout_above="@+id/imageView4" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show what you've tried...

Comment: how to make a selection of xml files for the size of tablets?

Comment: Which image do you want to have absolute position?